# htaccess rewrite rule with forward slash error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an htaccess rewrite rule setup to reroute the URL to index.php and have pretty SEO friendly URLs.

It looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php [L]
```

This works great except that when for example I type www.site.com/one/two
which reroutes to index.php but the css and image files are missing.

How do I allow for a slash in the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add your css to the html add a `/` in front of the path like so:

```
<link href="/styles/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

That should fix your problem. You should do the same with javascript files.

That `/` tells the browser that the path is relative to the root of the website.

Comment: omg I knew about that but can't believe I missed that. Thank you very much for your time in answering a noob question :D

Comment: No problem, we all have our dark hours.